# Android code for Setting Wallpaper taking too long

Tags: android, optimization, wallpaper

Basically have been trying to set the wallpaper through a location based app.

```
WallpaperManager wManager;
Bitmap bitmap;
try {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(wallSrc);
    wManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    wManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Profiling the code points out that the line

```
wManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

is acting as the culprit here. This seems to be taking an irrationally high amount of time to execute. Any faster mechanism to do the same? or to rephrase the question- Knowing the path to an image, what would be the fastest way to set it as a wallpaper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`setStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) might be faster as you don't have to manually decode the bitmap. Realistically though, *something* has to decode it... Most likely you're just using too large of a bitmap.